# SSL connection error

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl, certificate, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to mysql from a c# app using ssl. the following is my connection string:

```
 server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        database = "sqlserver";
        uid = "sqlserver";
        password = "password";
        cert_file = "client-cert.pfx";      
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + "; CertificateFile=" + cert_file + "; CertificatePassword=admin; SslMode=Required";
```

this is the error:

> System.IO.IOException: Received an
>   unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. at
>   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings) at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() at

I thought the problem was my file but now i know it is not... so i am lost

Comment: Does the ssl certificate specify a hostname pattern?

Comment: probably this issue - http://www.limilabs.com/blog/received-unexpected-eof-0-bytes-from-transport-stream

Answer (score 0):

```
server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
```

Most of the time, SSL certificates define a hostname pattern (e.g. *.google.com).  During the SSL authentication, the hostname is verified as being from the correct domain.  Using the IP address for the server will cause this check to fail.

I would try to set the hostname as server and see if you get different results.

Comment: may be the problem come from my openssl instalation. i have installed openssl 64 bit downloaded from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html. Do i need to include anything in visual studio as well? can that be the problem?